# Remove Run Time Permission for current location in Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to create an app. App asking every time location Access in Marsh Mallow, always when we open the app. Please suggested the best Process for solve my problem. using following code-

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
//for marshmallow
    final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you already given permission? If not, it is normal to ask for permission before doing such task.

Comment: its bczz you are asking permission every time

Comment: before asking permission check whether its already granted by user or not and then ask..  try this lib: 


https://github.com/UttamPanchasara/RuntimePermission

Comment: See @Uttams idea in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please reflect your code yourself. Think about the order of requesting and checking the permission. You should check the permission before you're asking for it. This makes sure to prevent asking if the permission was already granted...

Have a look at the [example provided by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and consider adapting this example for your needs:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)     {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Additionally you should overwrite the callback method `onRequestPermissionsResult` to handle the user's `grantResults`.

```
// Callback with the request from calling requestPermissions(...)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
    if (requestCode == READ_CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Edit:

This is thecode which you should change

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]    {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,     android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    return;
}
```

For further reading have a look at the article [Understanding App Permissions](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-App-Permissions)

Comment: if else conditions where should i put

Answer (score 0):

Try writting in if else, if permission is not given ask for it or else do what you want to do.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            } else {
               // do your stuff
            }
```

and also override onRequestPermissionsResult and apply your code afer you have granted permissions.